# How to print a list as a table

Tags: python, list

I have a list, lets say:

```py
list = ['UA2483', 'ORD', 'Jan 1', '09:00', 'LAS', 'Jan 1', '10:54', '0 Stop\n-', '3h 54m', 'BASIC ECONOMY', 'USD $230.90', 'UA1488', 'ORD', 'Jan 1', '13:00', 'LAS', 'Jan 1', '14:57', '0 Stop\n-', '3h 57m', 'BASIC ECONOMY', 'USD $230.90']
```

I would like to print 1st 11 entries of the list in a row and then the next 11 in another row:

```
UA2483 ORD Jan 1 09:00 LAS Jan 1 10:54 0 Stop 3h 54m BASIC ECONOMY USD $230.90

UA1488 ORD Jan 1 13:00 LAS Jan 1 14:57 0 Stop 3h 57m BASIC ECONOMY USD $230.90
```

I also want to remove "\n" while printing so that it does not go to the next row.

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76623237/edit) your question to include what you have tried so far to solve the issue? See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.join` + `str.replace`:

```py
lst = [...] # your list from the question

N = 11
for i in range(0, len(lst), N):
    print(' '.join(lst[i:i+N]).replace('\n-', ''))
```

Prints:

```
UA2483 ORD Jan 1 09:00 LAS Jan 1 10:54 0 Stop 3h 54m BASIC ECONOMY USD $230.90
UA1488 ORD Jan 1 13:00 LAS Jan 1 14:57 0 Stop 3h 57m BASIC ECONOMY USD $230.90
```

---

**Note**: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it *shadows* the Python builtin.

Answer (score 0):

You could use zip with an iterator (e.g. one that removes the \n) and print in a single line using new lines as a separator:

```
i = (s.split("\n")[0] for s in lst)
print(*map(" ".join,zip(*[i]*11)),sep="\n")
```

output:

```
UA2483 ORD Jan 1 09:00 LAS Jan 1 10:54 0 Stop 3h 54m BASIC ECONOMY USD $230.90
UA1488 ORD Jan 1 13:00 LAS Jan 1 14:57 0 Stop 3h 57m BASIC ECONOMY USD $230.90
```

Answer (score 0):

[`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) will handle the specific value you'd like to replace.
If your data has varying column widths then the table will be misaligned unless you enforce alignment ahead of time. We can use [`str.ljust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) to enforce the alignment:

```
flight_data = [
    ['UA2483', 'ORD', 'Jan 1', '09:00', 'LAS', 'Jan 1', '10:54', '0 Stop\n-', '3h 54m', 'BASIC ECONOMY', 'USD $230.90'],
['DL440', 'JFK', 'Jan 7', '09:20', 'LAX', 'Jan 7', '12:45', '0 Stop\n-', '5h 25m', 'BUSINESS', 'USD $800.00'],
    ['UA662', 'LAS', 'Jan 8', '14:00', 'SFO', 'Jan 8', '15:20', '0 Stop\n-', '1h 20m', 'ECONOMY PLUS', 'USD $200.50'],
    ['AA223', 'ORD', 'Jan 9', '11:30', 'DFW', 'Jan 9', '13:45', '0 Stop\n-', '2h 15m', 'BASIC ECONOMY', 'USD $150.00'],
    ['DL765', 'LHR', 'Jan 10', '20:00', 'ATL', 'Jan 11', '05:30', '1 Stop', '9h 30m', 'PREMIUM ECONOMY', 'USD $700.25']
]

flight_data_stripped = [[item.replace('\n-', '') for item in row] for row in flight_data]
column_widths = [max(len(str(row[i])) for row in flight_data_stripped) for i in range(len(flight_data_stripped[0]))] # we figure out the longest string in each column

def print_row(row):
    for i, cell in enumerate(row):
        print(str(cell).ljust(column_widths[i] + 2), end='')
    print()

for row in flight_data_stripped:
    print_row(row)
```

```
UA2483  ORD  Jan 1   09:00  LAS  Jan 1   10:54  0 Stop  3h 54m  BASIC ECONOMY    USD $230.90  
DL440   JFK  Jan 7   09:20  LAX  Jan 7   12:45  0 Stop  5h 25m  BUSINESS         USD $800.00  
UA662   LAS  Jan 8   14:00  SFO  Jan 8   15:20  0 Stop  1h 20m  ECONOMY PLUS     USD $200.50  
AA223   ORD  Jan 9   11:30  DFW  Jan 9   13:45  0 Stop  2h 15m  BASIC ECONOMY    USD $150.00  
DL765   LHR  Jan 10  20:00  ATL  Jan 11  05:30  1 Stop  9h 30m  PREMIUM ECONOMY  USD $700.25
```